# Who invented the Mikraot Gedolot?

Tags: history, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash, commentaries

Whose idea was the Mikraot Gedolot and when was it first published? Mikraot Gedolot is a Humash with a collection of commentaries very popular in Jewish circles today.

Comment: Check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikraot_Gedolot). It doesn't cite any sources though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first Mikraot Gedolot was printed by Daniel Bromberg in 1516-1517.

http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA

Comment: Interesting that the Hebrew and English WP articles have slightly different information.

Comment: I noticed that, However the Hebrew one seemed to be more thorough.

Comment: @IsaacMoses In most of cases WikiPedia articles are different in different languages. Sometimes there are just slight differences, but sometimes there are major differences.